# How to convert form Hex color code #RRGGBB to R,G,B values

Tags: android, colors, picker

I'm doing project about color picker. I found the samples code at site: 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-color-picker-application-using-ambilwarna-color-picker-library/

When I click button "OK", systems show such as: -1232323, -1023445, -154525,... because in library, color have 4 bytes: alpha, red, green, blue. Actually, I don't understand about color in android. I'm just have learned android for 1 week.

But I want to get values of Red, Green, Blue when I click button "OK". How I do it?
Please help me
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
  int color = Color.parseColor("#RRGGBB");
```

and then

```
  int red = Color.red(color);
  int green = Color.green(color);
  int blue = Color.blue(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the corresponding methods of Color class: [red](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#red(int)), [green](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#green(int)), blue or alpha.
For example,

```
final int myGreen = Color.green(-1232323);
```